# Java: How to access Window credential from IE browser

Tags: java, windows, security, java-ee-6, tomcat7

How can I retrieve the credentials for the currently logged-in Windows user that accessing my web application in java

From a standalone application, I can access the user id of a logged-in window user using

```
com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem NTSystem = new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem();
System.out.println(NTSystem.getName());
```

However, this will not work for web app, since it will always print out the id of the user that running Tomcat, not the id of the user who accessing the web application

I see this being done before, that if I access a website via IE, it automatically log me in, but I use other browser, then a log-in box pop out. Any idea how to achieve this, thank you?

My web app is written in JSF with Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a library that can receive the Kerberos token that IE will sent (assuming that it is configured with Integrated Windows Authentication).

There are multiple approaches/libraries to doing this, which are well documented on Apache's site for Tomcat. Here you go: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

You have some different options to achieve this. Tomcat has some suggestions on their [homepage](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html). I've used both IIS fronting and the spring-security kerberos extension and they work just fine.